# ::-webkit-scrollbar is it possible to make the scrollbar-thumb grow instead moving?

Tags: css

I would like my scroll to work like this when the user scrolls. e.g to start to fill up instead of moving.
[image]
[image]

Is it possible to make the scroll-thumb grow or to style the scrollbar-track-piece different before and after the thumb?

Comment: have you look [this](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/s/scrollbar/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a small example how to implement this loader

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {
   var html = document.documentElement;
   let step = 100 / (html.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight);
   let loader = document.getElementById("scrollprogress");
   loader.style.width = (step * html.scrollTop) + "%";

})
```

```css
#scrollprogress {
   height: 5px;
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   background: orange;
}

.backgr {
   position: fixed;
   left: 0;
   top: 0;
   width: 100vw;
   height: 5px;
   background: lightgrey;
   z-index: -1;
}

.box {
   height: 3000px;
}
```

```html
<div id="scrollprogress"></div>
<div class="backgr"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Was hoping for a css solution but this looks pretty smooth and will work crossbrowser

Answer (score 1):

You can approximate this using negative box shadow:

```css
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 1em;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background-color: orange;
  box-shadow:-1000vmax -1000vmax 0px 1000vmax orange;
}

body  {
 width:300vw;
 height:300vh;
 background:linear-gradient(60deg,red,blue,orange);
 margin:0;
}

html {
  background:#fff;
}
```

Comment: Really nice solution :)
But this won't work in all browsers like firefox right?